# Selecting related data without selecting foreign key from subquery

Tags: postgresql, select, postgresql-13

cities

| id | name | county_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | City1 | 1 |
| 2 | City2 | 1 |
| 3 | City3 | 2 |
| 4 | City4 | 2 |

counties

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | County1 |
| 2 | County2 |

Hello,
I would like to select all city names from related county by enetring a city name.
I can do it via subquery, but is there any other way to achieve this?

```
SELECT name
FROM cities
WHERE cities.county_id =
      (SELECT county_id
       FROM cities
       WHERE name = 'City1'
       LIMIT 1);

result => "City1, City2"
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could use a join - but what's wrong with the subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join`:

```
select name from cities c
inner join 
( SELECT county_id 
  FROM cities 
  WHERE name = 'City1' 
  LIMIT 1) as d 
on c.county_id=d.county_id ;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/905fc/1